# How to insert a input element of type="time" using PHP into a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two inputs(start and end time) with type="time". Using PHP I want to insert these values into a table named 'allotdate'. This table have two columns- starttime and endtime. Both are of type- time.
Code written so far:
HTML and PHP:

```
<input type="time" name="st1" /><br/><input type="time" name="et1"/>
<input type="submit" name="allot" class="gobutton" value="Allot Dates"/>

if(isset($_POST['allot']))
{  
  $c="$_POST[st1]";
  $d="$_POST[et1]";

  mysql_query("insert into allotdate values('$c','$d')");  
      if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
        {

   echo "<script>alert('You have successfully alloted')</script>";
    }
}
```

But this is not working. No values are inserted and neither the alert message pops up. Any suggestions?

Comment: kindly describe your table Ex: `desc allotdate;`

Comment: Once you've solved your issue, do a search on "MySQL Injection", as your code is vulnerable to attack. You should also move from the PHP function `mysql`to `mysqli`.

Comment: The table has following desc:
starttime  time
endtime   time

Answer (score 1):

Change the following lines:

```
  $c="$_POST[st1]";
  $d="$_POST[et1]";
```

To

```
  $c=$_POST['st1'];
  $d=$_POST['et1'];
```

You're trying to insert a string containing the value `$_POST[st1]` rather than the actual posted value.

Answer (score 0):

you need a form and a php tag but i think you already have if not you not realy smart but you can use the sql date function for more about sql date this post

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Obviously I had used form and php tags!  It is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="time" name="st1" /><br/><input type="time" name="et1"/>
<input type="submit" name="allot" class="gobutton" value="Allot Dates"/>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['allot']))
{
    $c=$_POST['st1'];
    $d=$_POST['et1'];

    mysql_query("insert into allotdate values('$c','$d')");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
    {

        echo "<script>alert('You have successfully alloted')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to rename the table `qteam`?